# How to allow access only for certain google-cloud-functions

Tags: google-compute-engine

Does anyone know what is the proper firewall configuration to allow a given VM to allow traffic only from certain cloud-functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict the API permissions of the [default GCE service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using_the_compute_engine_default_service_account) and change the "Cloud API access scopes" of your GCE instance also if needed (you can do this by clicking the "Edit" option on the details of your GCE instance).

Comment: Thank you but I tried that, I found out that access from functions to GCE instances on VPC are a beta feature. Does not seems to be possible to create a firewall rule and allow income traffic based on service account for source (works for instances on the same vpc but not for cloud functions for instance.)

Comment: What about this [function identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#per-function_identity) option? this is also a beta feature but maybe if you restrict the access to the service account could help you.

Comment: Would not work either. There's no support for private VPC access as you would do between two VMs. One alternative and it's what I ended up doing is to use Identity Access Proxy, but that requires a bunch of things: an LB, a valid certificate, and a domain

Comment: I created this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/124725544) so the team can work over this and add this option on the final release if approved by them.